# cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -S 9161306' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, emulation

how to fix
('cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -S 9161306' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package')
and
(Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.)
error when i launch the emulator.

Comment: or    Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely with your Android Emulator.

If so, the solution is to do a Cold Reboot of the Emulator:

(Open Android Virtual Device Manager from `Tools > AVD Manager`)
[image: Open AVD Manager]

(Right Click on the Virtual Device that is generating the error and choose `Cold Boot Now`)
[image: Choose Cold Boot Now]